# Hpricot XML text search

Tags: ruby, xml, hpricot

Hpricot + Ruby XML parsing and logical selection.

Objective: Find all title written by author Bob.

My XML file:

```
<rss>
<channel>
<item>
<title>Book1</title>
<pubDate>march 1 2010</pubDate>
<author>Bob</author>
</item>

<item>
<title>book2</title>
<pubDate>october 4 2009</pubDate>
<author>Bill</author>
</item>

<item>
<title>book3</title>
<pubDate>June 5 2010</pubDate>
<author>Steve</author>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>

#my Hpricot, running this code returns no output, however the search pattern works on its own.
 (doc % :rss % :channel / :item).each do |item|

        a=item.search("author[text()*='Bob']")

        #puts "FOUND" if a.include?"Bob"
        puts item.at("title") if a.include?"Bob"

  end
```

Comment: I've never seen an accessor like `(doc % :rss % :channel / :item)` used with Hpricot or Nokogiri.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ideas behind XPath is it allows us to navigate a DOM similarly to a disk directory:

```
require 'hpricot'

xml = <<EOT
<rss>
    <channel>
        <item>
            <title>Book1</title>
            <pubDate>march 1 2010</pubDate>
            <author>Bob</author>
        </item>

        <item>
            <title>book2</title>
            <pubDate>october 4 2009</pubDate>
            <author>Bill</author>
        </item>

        <item>
            <title>book3</title>
            <pubDate>June 5 2010</pubDate>
            <author>Steve</author>
        </item>

        <item>
            <title>Book4</title>
            <pubDate>march 1 2010</pubDate>
            <author>Bob</author>
        </item>

    </channel>
</rss>
EOT

doc = Hpricot(xml)

titles = (doc / '//author[text()="Bob"]/../title' )
titles # => #<Hpricot::Elements[{elem <title> "Book1" </title>}, {elem <title> "Book4" </title>}]>
```

That means: "find all the books by Bob, then look up one level and find the title tag".

I added an extra book by "Bob" to test getting all occurrences.

To get the item containing a book by Bob, just move back up a level:

```
items = (doc / '//author[text()="Bob"]/..' )
puts items # => nil
# >> <item>
# >>             <title>Book1</title>
# >>             <pubdate>march 1 2010</pubdate>
# >>             <author>Bob</author>
# >>         </item>
# >> <item>
# >>             <title>Book4</title>
# >>             <pubdate>march 1 2010</pubdate>
# >>             <author>Bob</author>
# >>         </item>
```

I also figured out what `(doc % :rss % :channel / :item)` is doing. It's equivalent to nesting the searches, minus the wrapping parenthesis, and these should all be the same in Hpricot-ese:

```
(doc % :rss % :channel / :item).size # => 4
(((doc % :rss) % :channel) / :item).size # => 4
(doc / '//rss/channel/item').size # => 4
(doc / 'rss channel item').size # => 4
```

Because `'//rss/channel/item'` is how you'd normally see an XPath accessor, and `'rss channel item'` is a CSS accessor, I'd recommend using those formats for maintenance and clarity.

Comment: Nice, I too often forget about `..` in XPath

Comment: @theTinMain With XPath is it possible to select the whole item group for Bob? I was trying `@items=(doc / "//rss/channel/item/author[text()='Bob']/../[self::title or self::pubDate]")`  according to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721928/xpath-to-select-multiple-tags) but that didn't work.

Comment: Well, your question says you want to "Find all title written by author Bob". If you want items move up one level and don't descend again. I'll add an example.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not set on Hpricot, here's one way to do this with XPath in [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/):

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML( my_rss_string )
bobs_titles = doc.xpath("//title[parent::item/author[text()='Bob']]")
p bobs_titles.map{ |node| node.text }
#=> ["Book1"]
```

**Edit**: @theTinMan's XPath also works well, is more readable, and may very well be faster:

```
bobs_titles = doc.xpath("//author[text()='Bob']/../title")
```

Comment: +1 for Nokogiri. It's supported by a great group of Ruby developers and, like Homer Simpson's doughnuts, there's nothing it can't do.

Comment: Yeah nokogiri is great and I do not see a reason to run hpricot these days.

Comment: +1 Michael Papile, I switched to Nokogiri from Hpricot after it exploded on some malformed RSS, and never looked back.