# How to ge two fields with one XPath?

Tags: php, parsing, xpath, xml-parsing

I have a XPath that gets div i want to read. How to read class and name of the div with one XPath?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721928/xpath-to-select-multiple-tags

Comment: @GeneSys Well.. if you think all XPath questions are duplicates than yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
        $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument(); 
        $xmlDoc->load( '<<your file>>>' ); 
    //$xmlDoc->loadHTML($sourceString); //-> if its a string you have
        $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
        $elements = $xpath->query("Your XPath");

        //if you are sure there is only one div, for the Xpath, you can use a index 0 in the next statement, else uou have to itereate it in a loop

    $node = $elements->item(0);

    $attrib1 = $node->attributes->getNamedItem("<attribute_name1>");
    $attrib2 = $node->attributes->getNamedItem("<attribute_name2>");
    $attrib3 = $node->attributes->getNamedItem("<attribute_name3>");
    ....



        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code selects all div's that have the attributes name and class. See below to find out how to select the information from the selected node.

```
<?php

    $xmlstring = '<root>' .
        '<div name="value1" class="value2" myarg="value3"></div>' .
        '<div name="value4"></div>' .
    '</root>';
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);

    // Select all div's that have attributes name and class
    $xpath = "//div[@name and @class]"; 
    var_dump($result = $xml->xpath($xpath));

    /* Outputs:
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
            ["@attributes"]=>
            array(3) {
              ["name"]=>
              string(6) "value1"
              ["class"]=>
              string(6) "value2"
              ["myarg"]=>
              string(6) "value3"
            }
          }
        }   
    */

    // note that only one iteration is performed
    // as the second div does not have an attribut
    // called 'class'.
    foreach($result as $element)
    {
        echo $element['name'];   // value1
        echo $element['class'];  // value2
    } 

    // or, if only one div is present in the document:
    echo $result[0]['name'];     // value1
    echo $result[0]['class'];    // value2  

?>
```