# XPath selecting same level node with different name

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm making different selection on this XML, but for most of them i'm not sure that i done the simplest solution, and for 2 of them i'm not able to provide a working solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE list[
<!ELEMENT list(man|woman)*>
<!ELEMENT man(sons,daughters)>
<!ATTLIST man name CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT man(sons,daughters)>
<!ATTLIST woman name CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT sons(man)*>
<!ELEMENT daughters(woman)*>

<list>
    <man name="Jean-Bernard">
        <sons>
            <man name="Marc-Antoine"/>
        </sons>
        <daughters>
            <woman name="Marie-Jeanne">
                <sons/>
                <daughters>
                    <woman name="Anne-Sophie"/>
                </daughters>
            </woman>
            <woman name="Rose-Marie">
                <daughters>
                    <woman name="Marie-Cécile"/>
                </daughters>
            </woman>
        </daughters>
    </man>
    <woman name="Marie-Jeanne">
        <sons>
            <man name="Ghislain-Auguste">
                <sons/>
            </man>  
        </sons>
        <daughters>
            <woman name="Rita-Lise">
            <sons>
                <man name="Alain-Luc"/>
                <man name="Jules-Edouard"/>
            </sons>
            </woman>
        </daughters>
    </woman>
</list>
```

What i have done :

- Selecting all women : `//woman`
- Selecting all women with the name "Marie Jeanne" : `//woman[@name='Marie-Jeanne']`
- Selecting all woman with a name which contains "Marie" : `//woman[contains(@name,Marie)]`

What i have done but this is not exact or i think it can be better :

- Selecting all women or men who have at least 2 children : `//*[sum(count(sons/man), count(daughters/woman)) >= 2]`
- Selecting all women or men who are grandparents : i'm totally stuck for this one i can't see how i can select with so much unknown. In my mind this is like that : `//*/*/*/*` . . . i don't understand how to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Selecting all women or men who have at least 2 children:

```
//*[(self::man or self::woman) and count(*/*) > 1]
```

---

> Selecting all women or men who are grandparents

```
//*[(self::man or self::woman) and */*/*/*]
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it easier to select all women or men who are grandparents you could use the "self" declarative [XPath to select multiple tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721928/xpath-to-select-multiple-tags):

```
//*[count(*[self::sons or self::daughters]/*[self::man or self::woman]/*[self::sons or self::daughters]/*[self::man or self::woman]) >= 1]
```