# XPath for the below condition

Tags: xml, xpath

Suppose I have the given XML

```
<StyleML>
<transaction>
<party>
<partyId>Party1</partyId>
<partyAlias>
    <partyAliasId>2323</partyAliasId>
    <partyAliasLongName>AQR LP</partyAliasLongName>
     </partyAlias>
     </party>
<party>
<partyId>Party2</partyId>
<partyAlias>
     <partyAliasId>2323</partyAliasId>
     <partyAliasLongName>Scotland</partyAliasLongName>
</partyAlias>
</party>
     <transactionParticipant>
          <counterpartyRef>Party2</counterpartyRef>
          <participantType>Counterparty Participant</participantType>
     </transactionParticipant>
     <transactionParticipant>
         <counterpartyRef>Party3</counterpartyRef>
         <participantType>Broker Participant</participantType>
     </transactionParticipant>
</transaction>
</StyleML>
```

Now I would like to populate the two XPath values as a single comma separated value.

For eg.  I would like to populate 2323,AQR LP i.e.[/styleml/transaction/party/partyAlias/partyAliasId ,/styleml/transaction/party/partyAlias/partyAliasLongName]

I have tried the | operator to join to XPath results , however Its populating only the first xpath data as an end result.

Answer (score 1):

### Fix

Be sure to respect tag case (`styelml`→`StyleML`).

### Solution using `or`

I would go to something like what is described in [XPath to select multiple tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/722251/802365):

```xml
/StyleML/transaction/party/partyAlias/*[self::partyAliasId or self::partyAliasLongName]
```

### Solution using `|` and `saxon`

Using [saxon XQuery](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!using-xquery/commandline) you can use the `/path/(a|b)` syntax:

```sh
java -cp "/path/to/saxon9ee.jar" net.sf.saxon.Query -s:"/path/to/file.xml" \
-qs:"/StyleML/transaction/party/partyAlias/(partyAliasId|partyAliasLongName)"
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <partyAliasId>2323</partyAliasId><partyAliasLongName>AQR LP</partyAliasLongName>
  <partyAliasId>2323</partyAliasId><partyAliasLongName>Scotland</partyAliasLongName>
```