# Select certain child nodes using xpath

Tags: xml, r, xpath

I am using the R function `xpathSApply` where I want to choose certain child nodes. At the moment I can only choose one child node e.g.

```
xpathSApply(dat, "//Establishment[AddressLine3='Mumbles']/BusinessName",xmlValue)
```

where this gives me a list of restaraunts where the child node `AddressLine3 = Mumbles`. There is also another child node I am interested in called Rating (full path is `//Establishment/Rating`). What I would like to do is bring back a pair of values, the `BusinessName` and `Rating` child nodes in one xPath query. Can this be done?

Comment: Can you share a sample of the xml. Should be very easy and I can get you the xpath.

Comment: here it is http://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS568en-GB.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use "|" to separate the 2 queries. But obviously it will return the values in the same vector, then you have to formate the result.

```
url <- "http://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS568en-GB.xml"
doc <- xmlParse(url)

datas <- xpathSApply(doc, "//EstablishmentDetail[AddressLine3='Mumbles']/BusinessName | //EstablishmentDetail[AddressLine3='Mumbles']/RatingValue", xmlValue)

data.frame(BusinessName = datas[seq(1, 117, by = 2)], RatingValue = datas[-seq(1, 117, by = 2)])
```

Comment: also I'm curious how the "-seq" works in the second column. Could you please elaborate on what that is doing?

Comment: `datas[-1]` is "datas" without his first element, `datas[-c(1, 2)]` "datas" without the 1st and 2nd elements. `datas[-seq(1, 117, by = 2)]` returns the vector "datas" without the elements indexed by the values in the vector produced by `seq(1, 117, by = 2)`. Though that was just for the example, it's not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The XPath query isn't R-specific, so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721928/xpath-to-select-multiple-tags) suggests

```
query <- "//EstablishmentDetail[AddressLine3='Mumbles']/
              *[self::BusinessName or self::RatingValue]"
```

which could be munged as

```
library(XML)
xml <- xmlParse("http://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS568en-GB.xml")
as.data.frame(split(vapply(xml[query], xmlValue, character(1)), 1:2))
```

But maybe it's clearer to write

```
query <- "//EstablishmentDetail[AddressLine3='Mumbles']"
xmlToDataFrame(xml[query])[, c("BusinessName", "RatingValue")]
```