# How to locate multiple attribute/tags present under single tag with xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Please refer to this sample code:

```
<div class="menu"> 
    <a href="one.html">One</a>
    <a href="two.html">Two</a>
    <button type="button">Three</button>
    <button type="button">Four</button>
        <div class="menu2">
            <a href="five.html">Five</a>
            <a href="six.html">Six</a>  
        </div>
        <div class="menu3">
            <a href="seven.html">Seven</a>
            <button type="button">Eight</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to locate 'a' tag and 'button' tag using single xpath.

I can do it using cssSelector with following code:

```
List<WebElement> list = d.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class='menu'] a, div[class='menu'] button"));

for (WebElement l: list) {
System.out.println(l.getText());
}
```

But I would like do it with xpath.

Comment: may duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721928/xpath-to-select-multiple-tags.

Comment: /div/*[self::a or self::button]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use below XPath to match both `a` and `button`:

```
//div[@class="menu"]//*[name()=("a" or "button")]
```

or

```
//div[@class="menu"]//*[self::a or self::button]
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for not including this in the original post.
But the actual code have more nested div, a and button tags as this
`<div class="menu"> 
 <a href="one.html">One</a>
 <a href="two.html">Two</a>
 <button type="button">Three</button>
 <button type="button">Four</button>
  <div class="menu2">
   <a href="five.html">Five</a>
   <a href="six.html">Six</a> 
  </div>
  <div class="menu3">
   <a href="seven.html">Seven</a>
   <button type="button">Eight</button>
  </div>
</div>`
this xpath only selects a and button tags within parent div not the ones within nested divs

Comment: Try `//div[@class="menu"]//*[name()=("a" or "button")]` or `//div[@class="menu"]//*[self::a or self::button]`

Comment: @Ami If you want to present all <a> and <button> blocks never mind in what <div> they are, then use simply //*[name() = (‘a’ or ‘button’)]

Comment: @Andersson `//div[@class="menu"]//*[name()=("a" or "button")]` Selects the nested divs too, but `//div[@class="menu"]//*[self::a or self::button]` works perfectly. 

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Jsoup to get all the data.Here I have some example:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);
Elements elements = doc.select("div.menu a");
for (Element element : elements) {
  String url = element.attr("href");
}
```