# Finding multiple types of tags with lxml findall() with xpath?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I would like to search an XML file for multiple tags.

I can evaluate these command separately:

```
tree.findall('.//title')
tree.findall('.//p')
```

but how can I evaluate them together in the same time. I am looking for a syntax like `.// title or .//p`

I tried this command from an SO post

```
tree.findall('.//(p|title)')
```

but I get this traceback error `SyntaxError: invalid descendant`

Comment: please can you add a sample of the xml  you are parsing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of traversing the tree two times and joining the node sets, it would be better to do one pass looking for a `*` wild-card tag name and checking for the tag name via `self::` ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/722251/771848)):

```
tree.xpath("//*[self::p or self::title]")
```

Demo:

```
In [1]: from lxml.html import fromstring

In [2]: html = """
    ...: <body>
    ...:     <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    ...:     <div>Other info</div>
    ...:     <title>Title 1</title>
    ...:     <span>
    ...:         <p>Paragraph 2</p>
    ...:     </span>
    ...:     <title>Title 2</title>
    ...: </body>
    ...: """

In [3]: root = fromstring(html)

In [4]: [elm.text_content() for elm in root.xpath("//*[self::p or self::title]")] 
Out[4]: ['Paragraph 1', 'Title 1', 'Paragraph 2', 'Title 2']
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
tree.xpath('.//p | .//title')
```

The result is the union of both node sets.

Comment: I tried this and I got `ValueError: Empty tag name`. Any thoughts on where this error is coming from?

Comment: The union operator (`|`) is not supported by `findall()`, but it works with `xpath()`. See https://lxml.de/FAQ.html#what-are-the-findall-and-xpath-methods-on-element-tree.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this bug. I corrected the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you @alecxe that traversing the tree two times is bad, however I find your solution to be 20 time slower than calling twice findall. Instead, the solution of @zw485 has comparable time with two findall calls:

```
el_l = tree.xpath(".//p | .//title ") #My recommendation
#66.4 µs ± 1.07 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

el_l   = tree.findall(".//p") + tree.findall(".//title")
#53.7 µs ± 1.84 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

el_l = tree.xpath(".//*[self::p or self::title]")
#1.11 ms ± 15.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

The disadvantage of multiple calls of findall is that the elements won't be sorted as they appear in the document. Also, with more items searched, findall time increases linearly, while xpath isn't:

```
el_l = tree.xpath(".//p|.//title|.//fig|.//table-wrap|.//media|.//graphic")
#113 µs ± 3.56 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

el_l   = (tree.findall(".//p")            + tree.findall(".//title") 
          + tree.findall(".//table-wrap") + tree.findall(".//fig")
          + tree.findall(".//media")      + tree.findall(".//graphic"))
#153 µs ± 5.98 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```