# C#-Selenium: How to use contains to find text between two elements?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to use one xpath to check both the below(span and option). How can we do this?

```
//Span
webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='someClass']//span[contains(text(),'Some text 1')]")).Displayed

//Option
webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='someClass']//option[contains(text(),'SOme text 2')]")).Displayed
```

I tried below xpaths, none of them worked, what could be wrong?

```
webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='someClass' and contains(text(), 'Some text 1')]"))
webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='someClass'] and [contains(text(),'Some text 1')]"))
webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='someClass'][contains(text(),'Some text 1')]"))
webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='someClass'] and (text(),'Some text 1')"))
```

Kindly check.

Comment: Post the html. What happened when you tried this?

Comment: @Guy - It didnt find. Which one of them is right per you? Sorry can`t share html.

Comment: I can't know which one is correct (if any of them) without seeing the html. You can try adding some wait and check for `iframe`, but that as far as we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match both span and option with a single xpath, you can use the * wildcard.

```
//div[@class='someClass']//*[contains(text(),'Some text 1')]
```

Also check [XPath to select multiple tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/721928/1630906) in case you want to select only spans and options with that text, not any other types of elements.