# can we search multiple pattern using etree findall() in xml?

Tags: python, xml, findall

For my case, I have to find few elements in the XML file and update their values using the `text` attribute. For that, I have to search xml element A, B and C. My project is using xml.etree and python language. Currently I am using:

```
self.get_root.findall(H/A/T)
self.get_root.findall(H/B/T)
self.get_root.findall(H/C/T)
```

The sample XML file:

```
<H><A><T>text-i-have-to-update</H></A></T>
<H><B><T>text-i-have-to-update</H></B></T>
<H><C><T>text-i-have-to-update</H></C></T>
```

As we can notice, only the middle element in the path is different. Is there a way to optimize the code using something like `self.get_root.findall(H|(A,B,C)|T)`? Any guidance in the right direction will do! Thanks!

I went through the similar question: [XPath to select multiple tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721928/xpath-to-select-multiple-tags) but it didn't work for my case

Update: maybe regular expression inside the findall()?

Comment: there are already answers on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721928/xpath-to-select-multiple-tags

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XPath to select multiple tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721928/xpath-to-select-multiple-tags)

Comment: Its a little different for my case, also I have to use findall() and above it some logic like regular-expression or something else @sim

Comment: Please edit your question and add a representative sample of the actual xml.

Comment: @JackFleeting just added. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html in your question is malformed; assuming it's properly formatted (like below), try this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """<root>
<H><A><T>text-i-have-to-update</T></A></H>
<H><B><T>text-i-have-to-update</T></B></H>
<H><C><T>text-i-have-to-update</T></C></H>
</root>"""

doc = ET.fromstring(data)
for item in doc.findall('.//H//T'):
    item.text = "modified text"
print(ET.tostring(doc).decode())
```

Output:

```
<root>
<H><A><T>modified text</T></A></H>
<H><B><T>modified text</T></B></H>
<H><C><T>modified text</T></C></H>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks! I am curious, just like it is treating the empty string as it can be any value, is it support regular expression as well? @Jack Fleeting

Comment: @AadilHoda People generally consider using regular expressions with html/xml to be a bad idea; that's what xpath expressions are used for.