# Parse XML into INT to sum numbers up

Tags: javascript, xpath

I have an XML that I'm trying to get a sum out of. The number is either 0 or 1, and I want to get a sum of all the numbers. The XML looks like this:

```xml
<alerts>
    <alert1>0</alert1>
    <alert2>1</alert2>
    <alert3>1</alert3>
    <alert4>0</alert4>
</alerts>
```

My current code (wrong) looks like this:

```js
xpath = require('xpath');
xmldom = require('xmldom');

doc = new xmldom.DOMParser().parseFromString("sourceXml");

var count = xpath.select("alerts/alert1", doc).toString();
count += xpath.select("alerts/alert2", doc).toString();
count += xpath.select("alerts/alert3", doc).toString();
count += xpath.select("alerts/alert4", doc).toString();


var result = count;
```

Obviously since they're strings it results in "0110" as a string and not "2" as an INT. I tried wrapping each in parseInt but that just returns NaN. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

```
parseInt(xpath.select("alerts/alert3", doc).toString());

parseInt(xpath.select("alerts/alert3", doc));
```

Tried both but I'm not very experienced with JavaScript so it could be a syntax issue.

Comment: Okay, so show _how_ did you wrap them in parseInt? Can you show that code? (also, use parseFloat, unless you _really_ need an integer radix)

Comment: i would suggest to Console.Log(xpath.select("alerts/alert1", doc).toString()) and see what you get, before trying to parse it.
Also, default the count to 0 (var count = 0) instead of a value from xpath.

Comment: @StealthGhost please don't answer detail questions in comments, [put those details in your post](/help/how-to-ask). I didn't ask "for me", I asked so that you could update your post so that _everyone_ who might want to help solve your problem has the information they need =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans 

Sorry, fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `xpath.select()` [documentation](https://github.com/goto100/xpath/blob/master/docs/xpath%20methods.md#xpathselectexpression-node-single)...

> The return value is determined based on the result type of the expression (which can always be predicted ahead of time based on the expression's syntax):
>
> - A boolean value if the expression evaluates to a boolean value.
> - **A number if the expression evaluates to a numeric value.**
> - A string if the expression evaluates to a string.
> - If the expression evaluates to a nodeset:
>
>   - An array of 0 or more nodes if `single` is unspecified or falsy
>   - A single node (the first node in document order) or `undefined` if `single` is truthy

All your results are arrays, each containing a single node.

You can actually coerce the values to be numeric automatically by using the XPath [number function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/number)

```js
const count = xpath.select("number(alerts/alert1)", doc)
 + xpath.select("number(alerts/alert2)", doc)
 + xpath.select("number(alerts/alert3)", doc)
 + xpath.select("number(alerts/alert4)", doc)
```

---

Perhaps an easier option would be to simply use the XPath [sum function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/sum)

```js
const count = xpath.select(
  "sum(alerts/*[self::alert1 or self::alert2 or self::alert3 or self::alert4])",
  doc
)
```

<sub>See also [XPath to select multiple tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/722251/283366)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with this:

```
const count = xpath.select("sum(alerts/*)", doc)
```